# Can I get data from a document in a sub-collection from firebase using flutter if I don't know the document ID?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named users in which a document is created, upon registering, with the document ID being the same as the userID (generated by cloud Firestore automatically)

Within a user's specific document I've created a sub-collection named "addresses". A user can store any number of addresses and they would be saved as individual documents within this collection.

In my application, I am able to add a new address which is then displayed in a list along with all the other addresses he/she has added (this is done by reading each document within the "addresses" sub-collection)

Note: Each new document within the sub-collection has an auto-generated ID assigned to it.

My question is, is there a way for me to read a specific document within this sub-collection without knowing its documentID, and if so, will I be able to edit/delete only this once specific document.

(For example: User A's document has three addresses all stored as separate documents within the "addresses" sub-collection. User A wants to edit/delete document number 2 from these three documents. How will I go about letting him view and edit/delete that document).

I am very new to Flutter and Firebase (started 2 weeks ago) so I'm sorry if my question doesn't make sense :3.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is pretty simple and have several solution there for I need your code to answer an appropriate answer.  Can you share your code that list address so I will be able to answer your question?

Comment: "User A wants to edit/delete document number 2 from these three documents" You will need to know something about document number 2 that uniquely identifies it, for example its document ID, which you typically get when you read the documents from the database initially.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for the quick response! I messed around with my code yesterday and got it working the same way that @FrankvanPuffelen suggested in his comment above. If I have any further queries I'll be sure to use this platform again.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed around with my code and googled solutions for a bit and figured out a way to access the document. For anyone else with the same query, ill try to explain what I did briefly as best I can.

Basically, I had no reference to the document ID as it was being generated automatically when I was adding data to a document through my flutter code:

```
if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
     FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(documentId)
        .collection('pickup_addresses')
        .doc()
        .add({
              'address': _addressController.text,
              'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
   });
}
```

As @Frank van Puffelen suggested in the comment above, I needed something which uniquely identifies the document in order to retrieve its data. For this reason I created a variable of type String and stored a uniquely generated document ID inside it. I then created a document with this same ID as well as stored it in a field within this new document:

```
  String id = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('usres')
      .doc(documentId)
      .collection('pickup_addresses')
      .doc()
      .id;

  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(documentId)
        .collection('pickup_addresses')
        .doc(id)
        .set({
             'address': _addressController.text,
             'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
             'docID': id
    });
  }
```

I am aware that this might not be the perfect solution and there might be a much easier way to approach this problem. If so, I would love to know what I can do different.

I hope this solution helps someone out there stuck at the same place I was for hours on end!

Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that all of this is going on in an `onPressed: () {},` block in my code.